# How can I color the text on each other input?

Tags: html, css, input, textcolor

I've made 2 input type="text". And I want to color the texts on them in different colors. Only in css file.(Not in html file.) How can I color them?

> HTML

```
<form class="js-form form">
  <input type="text" name="write_name" placeholder="What is your name?" />
</form>

<form class="js-toDoForm">
  <input type="text" name="write_todo" placeholder="Write a to do" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply add a class name like this:

```
<form class="js-form form">
  <input class="firstinput" type="text" name="write_name" placeholder="What is your name?" />
</form>

<form class="js-toDoForm">
  <input class="secondinput" type="text" name="write_todo" placeholder="Write a to do" />
</form>
```

and the css like this:

```
    .firstinput {
       //write your styles
     }

    .secondinput {
       //write your styles
     }
```

Hope it helped you:) IG: @lindenkoppejan

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted to know!

Answer (score 2):

simply make new style for example like this

```
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

after that, use the class where you want to use the color like this

```
<form class="js-form form">
  <input type="text" class="text-red" name="write_name" placeholder="What is your name?" />
</form>

<form class="js-toDoForm">
  <input type="text" class="text-blue" name="write_todo" placeholder="Write a to do" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.js-form input {
  //write your styles

 }

.js-toDoForm input {
//write your styles
}

<!-- OR -->

<form class="js-form form"><input class="input_one" type="text" name="write_name" placeholder="What is your name?" /></form>

<form class="js-toDoForm"><input class="input_two" type="text" name="write_todo" placeholder="Write a to do" /></form>

<!-- And write your styles -->

.input_one {
//write your styles
  color: red;
}

.input_two {
//write your styles
   color: blue;
 }
```